# Make the CTA button stick to the bottom of the page when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a CTA button that sticks to the bottom of the page after page scroll reaches to some extent. Kindly look at the image below:

[image: CTA button interaction]

The rules follow:

1. On load, it should be on the original position of the CTA button.
2. When the page is getting scrolled, the CTA button will follow.
3. When the CTA button reaches to the top of the window, the button will move to the bottom-right corner and remains sticky over there.

Any codepen, jsfiddle or website references about this kind of interaction will be appreciated.

Comment: @xmastertje your solution will not meet his 3rd point

Comment: This is a good job for the intersectionobserver: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: I missed one thing on my 3rd rule, there's should be a transition effect when the CTA button move to the bottom-right corner.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this like using plugins or using simple CSS and JavaScript(below example). If you are looking for animation to button on the scroll you can make some adjustments in CSS with animation code or I guess some of the plugins are already doing this.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var btn = document.getElementById("floatBtn");
var sticky = btn.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    btn.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    btn.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}



.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.keka {
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}

#floatBtn {
  background: #004567;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 20px;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.content{
 height: 1900px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Header of the page</h2>
            <p>Some content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="keka">
            <button id="floatBtn">Floating button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet ex eu nulla interdum fermentum a at est. Vestibulum vehicula augue et nisl porta, at pretium leo consequat. Suspendisse sit amet semper nisi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In vehicula elit ut efficitur mollis. Nam vehicula pulvinar pulvinar. Curabitur neque purus, placerat eget nulla iaculis, tincidunt euismod lectus. Praesent facilisis at sem sit amet sagittis. Cras sagittis mi vel ornare convallis. Morbi tempus tempus lacus, eget lacinia magna porttitor non. Praesent tellus quam, molestie tincidunt libero sit amet, luctus viverra velit. Etiam vestibulum aliquam posuere. Praesent a dapibus sem. Sed cursus mi sit amet nisl maximus, eget varius lectus consectetur. Mauris molestie ac mi non malesuada. Proin faucibus sem vitae ex blandit tempor. Donec ut diam in tellus malesuada lacinia maximus non arcu. Proin blandit nisl at lacus feugiat, et auctor lectus viverra. Donec convallis eleifend ligula sagittis viverra. Vivamus mattis, felis et finibus maximus, diam felis vestibulum odio, eget efficitur tellus magna nec ante. Sed porta elit commodo nisi efficitur, in egestas nibh maximus. Integer nec leo ac ligula semper finibus at rhoncus felis. In pellentesque tincidunt pretium. Ut imperdiet eu nisi quis molestie. Cras lectus turpis, aliquam ut egestas ac, condimentum quis sem. In nec lorem dolor. Fusce non velit nec purus aliquet ultricies porttitor at metus. Donec et libero id nunc viverra dictum vel et sem. Integer tellus ligula, posuere quis dignissim sit amet, suscipit sit amet arcu. Vestibulum nec sodales magna, vitae varius justo. Ut ut felis a odio gravida malesuada eu ut lectus. Suspendisse quis nisl vel sem cursus luctus ac in nibh. Praesent at velit ac dolor convallis condimentum. Maecenas ac sagittis odio. In luctus eros sit amet accumsan maximus. Integer non dictum magna, at viverra urna. Mauris lacinia sodales nibh in scelerisque. Ut viverra ante ut nunc commodo, eu varius ipsum rutrum. Morbi dictum sodales dignissim. In eu finibus arcu. In consectetur eleifend libero. Aliquam purus felis, faucibus et rutrum non, consequat at metus. Cras ultricies metus eget rhoncus pulvinar. Quisque hendrerit at lectus fringilla aliquam. Sed viverra tellus tellus, eget fermentum mi ultrices in. Cras auctor, tortor quis eleifend aliquet, dui orci volutpat erat, quis sagittis nisl nisi at lacus. Suspendisse non condimentum orci. Quisque in elit mi. Praesent malesuada nibh a sapien fermentum vehicula. In in felis nibh. Nunc vitae turpis et est aliquet tempor vulputate volutpat neque. Vestibulum ut sapien sit amet diam sodales convallis sit amet euismod urna. In vehicula fermentum est, non porttitor risus pellentesque quis. Fusce condimentum mauris ut felis fringilla maximus. Nullam pharetra nisi nec enim sodales tincidunt. Morbi imperdiet felis eget lacus sagittis ornare. Donec euismod metus at erat luctus, non ullamcorper nunc ultricies. Sed sit amet vestibulum urna, et faucibus felis. Curabitur non mollis arcu, ut rhoncus leo. Integer sagittis iaculis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's great. But i missed one thing on my third rule, there's should be a transition effect when the "Floating button" move to bottom-right corner.